# How to get max value of related entity in Entity Framework most effectively

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I would like to get list of categories with most recent product in category.

I am using Entity Framework Core 2.1.

I have tried like this, but it is very slow

```
var categories = context.Categories.Select(x => new {
    x.Id,
    Product = x.Products.OrderByDescending(y => y.Date).Select(y => y.Name).FirstOrDefault()
}
```

Comment: Likely because you're retrieving every `y.Name` and then grabbing the first. Use `.FirstOrDefault().Name` to only retrieve one row.

Comment: What you have tried in 2.1.1 translates to single SQL which should be ok. First check if the same happens in you case (single SQL query and not client evaluation). Second eventually add index to `Product` by `(CategoryId, Date)`

Comment: Have you look at the generated query? Also, if you have no index on the Date column of `Products`, it has to do a table scan, meaning it has to read all the entries of the table just to give you the latest one.

Answer (score 1):

That LINQ query should generate a single SQL Query, which should be fast.

Something like:

```
SELECT [t].[CategoryId], (
    SELECT TOP(1) [r].[Name]
    FROM [Products] AS [r]
    WHERE [t].[CategoryId] = [r].[CategoryId]
    ORDER BY [r].[Date] DESC
) AS [FirstName]
FROM [Categorys] AS [t]
```

Here's a sample with 100 categories, each with 1000 products to test.  Code-first will create an index on Product.CategoryId, but even without that, this isn't an expensive query.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;

namespace EfCoreTest
{

    public class Category
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Product> Readings { get; } = new HashSet<Product>();
    }
    public class Product
    {
        public int ProductId{ get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }


    }

    public class Db : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Category> Categorys { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("server=.;database=EfCoreTest;Integrated Security=true");
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            using (var db = new Db())
            {

                db.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                db.Database.EnsureCreated();

                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    var t = new Category();

                    for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
                    {
                        var product = new Product()
                        {
                            Category = t,
                            Date = DateTime.Now,
                            Name = $"Category {j}{i}"

                        };
                        db.Add(product);
                    }
                    db.Add(t);


                }
                db.SaveChanges();



            }
            using (var db = new Db())
            {
                var q = db.Categorys.Select(t => new
                {
                    t.CategoryId,
                    FirstName = t.Readings.OrderByDescending(r => r.Date).Select(r => r.Name).FirstOrDefault()
                });

                var l = q.ToList();

                Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to exit.");
                Console.ReadKey();

            }

        }
    }
}
```